# google heatmaps including count of points

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, geolocation, heatmap

I have working code for my google heatmap.  Quick overview of what it does:

1) queries mysql DB to pull lat/long for all records (initially)
2) Drop down select box allows for filtering (basically just amends the SQL query in PHP)
3) Heatmap is a Json array (using php json_encode($SQL_Results))

so the code I have right now works perfectly - however, I wish to add more to the map.

My question is - is it possible to pull a count of all results for a particular location (I'm using postal code to generate lat/long) and display them over the heatmap?

An Example would be ; 100 results for location x ... and as you zoom in and dissipate the heatmap, it would amend the number.

I have tried looking for similar functionality but can only find information on adding markers/images to results - I need dynamic numbers displaying from results.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Here's the relevant code I used to create the heatmap:

```
<?PHP
$LatLng = "select inp.lat, inp.long from locations inp";
$results = db_query($LatLng);

$mapCoords = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var places = [];
var coords = <?php echo json_encode($mapCoords); ?>;

for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i].lat, coords[i].long));
}

var map, pointarray, heatmap;
var gradient = [
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
        'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
        'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
        'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ];

var Data = places;

function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.892473,-2.932931),    
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(Data);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray,
            dissipating: true,
            radius: 35

        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
        heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
        heatmap.set('opacity', '0.9');
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, think I was looking at the wrong approach - my initial idea was to pull a count from the DB of returned rows and display a custom marker with dynamic text.  The solution I found (and was really simple to implement!) was Google marker clustering using MarkerClusterer.js.  For me, I just downloaded the JS, pointed to it in my code and added the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MarkerClusterer.js"></script> 
var places = [];
var markers = [];

var coords = <?php echo json_encode($mapCoords); ?>;

for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i].lat, coords[i].long));
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i].lat, coords[i].long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

`

and at the end set the cluster and add some options:

```
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

That's pretty much it - as I zoom in I get the change in counts and now I just need to work on custom markers with infowindows.  Hope this helps anyone else in the same situation.